# Extract metrics and populate data frame from multiple confusionMatrix's

Tags: r, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I have a number of confusionMatrix outputs for a variety of different classification models. I would like to extract the model metrics from each confusion matrix (i.e. Sensitivity --> Balanced Accuracy, or all metrics from cf_1$byClass) to populate a data frame. I would like the data frame to contain all these metrics, as well as a label for which confusion matrix it came from. Can anyone help me figure out how to do this? Please see below for a reproducible example:

```
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)

df_1 <- data.frame(x = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 20, replace = T),
                      y = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 20, replace = T))

df_2 <- data.frame(x = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 20, replace = T),
                      y = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 20, replace = T))

cf_1 <- confusionMatrix(df_1$y, df_1$x)
cf_2 <- confusionMatrix(df_2$y, df_2$x)

# I would like a dataframe with each of these, as well as column for the associated confusion matrix name
cf_1$byClass
cf_2$byClass
```

My desired output would look like this, except with all relevant metrics:

```
x = c(0.2, 0.4)
y = c(0.5, 0.6)
z = c("cf_1", "cf_2"
      )

output <- data.frame(Sensitivity = x, Specificity = y, Model = z)
```

**Update**

This is the solution that I came up with, it's not pretty, but it works. That being said, still open to seeing if anyone can come up with a cleaner, more efficient way to do this!

```
model_names <- c("cf_1", "cf_2")
model_metrics <- list()
for (i in 1:length(model_names)) {
     for (j in model_names) {
          model <- eval(as.name(j))
          results <- model$byClass %>% round(digits = 3)
          results <- c(model = j, results)
          model_metrics[[j]] <- results
     }
}

model_metrics <- do.call(rbind, model_metrics) %>% 
     data.frame %>% 
     `rownames<-`(NULL)

model_metrics
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches (btw I think you have a type in your example, `df_1` used twice)

```
# Base R
output <- data.frame(rbind(cf_1$byClass, cf_2$byClass))
output$model = c('cf_1', 'cf_2')

# dplyr version
output <- bind_rows(cf_1$byClass, cf_2$byClass, .id = 'model')
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks so much and appreciate the flag on df_1, have gone ahead and updated it!

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)

df_1 <- data.frame(x = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 20, replace = T),
                      y = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 20, replace = T))

df_2 <- data.frame(x = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 20, replace = T),
                      y = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 20, replace = T))

cf_1 <- confusionMatrix(df_1$y, df_1$x, mode = "sens_spec")
cf_2 <- confusionMatrix(df_2$y, df_2$x, mode = "sens_spec")

bind_rows(stack(cf_1$byClass), stack(cf_2$byClass), .id = "id") %>% 
  filter(ind %in% c("Sensitivity", "Specificity")) %>% 
  spread(id, values) %>% 
  rename(metric = ind, mod1 = "1", mod2 = "2")


#>        metric      mod1 mod2
#> 1 Sensitivity 0.4285714  0.5
#> 2 Specificity 0.6153846  0.4
```

**EDIT**
To get a dataframe just stack the `cf_1` list:

```
data.frame(stack(cf_1$byClass))
```

Comment: Thanks @c1au610_HH, this solution works, but I ideally wanted to hard-code in things as little as possible (i.e. not putting sensitivity, specificity....metrics no. 12). I think astrofunkswag's answer is the easiest approach as it only involves hardcoding in the confusion matrix name and nothing else